# Don't Allow User to Write Date in React DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a problem that i can't achieve. I wanted the user not to be allowed to write something on the input. I want them to choose from the calendar icon. My problem is that i user can write something on the input. I have achieved it using `DatePicker` instead of KeyboardDatePicker` BUT i also want the datepicker icon to show.

In short, i want to achieve the ff:

1. Don't allow user to write on the input.
2. Display datepicker icon
3. They should be able to click anywhere within the input

Pls check my codesandbox

[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-forest-4f8ld?file=/src/App.jsx)

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
  <KeyboardDatePicker
    error={false}
    helperText={null}
    autoOk
    fullWidth
    inputVariant="outlined"
    value={selectedDate}
    onChange={handleDateChange}
    format="MMM dd yyyy"
  />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Comment: What do you mean by display date picker icon? There is already a date picker icon in the sandbox.

Comment: @Dushan Randika. Yes it is there But i wanted to achieve both. not allow user to write and display datepicker at the SAME TIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, to not allow user to write on the input and display datepicker icon you could override `TextFieldComponent` in this way:

```
const TextFieldComponent = (props) => {
  return <TextField {...props} disabled={true} />;
};

const App = () => {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
         error={false}
         helperText={null}
         autoOk
         fullWidth
         inputVariant="outlined"
         value={selectedDate}
         onChange={handleDateChange}
         format="MMM dd yyyy"
         TextFieldComponent={TextFieldComponent} /*override TextFieldComponent*/
     />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-visvesvaraya-sgvbn?file=/src/App.jsx) your codesandbox modified.

**UPDATE**

If you want to allow user to click anywhere within the input, you can use `open` props and modify it by using `onClick` and `onClose` props in this way:

```
const App = () => {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
  const [dtopen, setDtOpen] = useState(false);       /*state var to open/close datepicker*/

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
       <KeyboardDatePicker
         error={false}
         helperText={null}
         autoOk
         fullWidth
         inputVariant="outlined"
         value={selectedDate}
         onChange={handleDateChange}
         format="MMM dd yyyy"
         TextFieldComponent={TextFieldComponent}
         onClick={() => setDtOpen(!dtopen)}     /*onClick to open/close datepicker*/
         open={dtopen}                          /*assign state var to open props*/
         onClose={() => setDtOpen(false)}      /*onClose to close datepicker*/ 
       />
   </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-visvesvaraya-sgvbn?file=/src/App.jsx) codesandbox modified.

Comment: Sorry i lack something. They should be able to click anywhere within the TexttField to open the DatePicker icon. Thank you.

Comment: @Joseph in this case it's just necessary to use `open` props and use it on `onClose` and `onClick` event. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-visvesvaraya-sgvbn?file=/src/App.jsx) codesandbox modified. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi there again. How can i make the `TextField` have `cursor: 'pointer'`? Right now only `datepicker icon` has that. Thank you

Comment: Hi @Joseph, it's just necessary to add `inputProps={{ style: { cursor: "pointer" } }}` to `TextField` component. I have modified the codesandbox.